How to geometrically derive stress transformation equations from Mohr's circle?
Consider the simple case of a 2D stress element with its corresponding Mohr's circle:

Now, for stress transformation using Mohr's circle, we rotate the diameter AB by twice the angle of rotation of element θ:

How to geometrically derive the following stress transformation equations from the above Mohr's circle:

My attempt:


Where am I making a mistake?

Can you do dot product of vectors? Original and rotated stresses should be in equilibrium.

@Tomáš Létal How to derive it using plain trigonometry from Mohr's circle?

Try a simplest example of pure tension $\sigma_x\neq 0, \sigma_y=\tau_{xy}=0$. If you rotate this by 90°, you will also get pure tension, only this time in the $y$ direction. However, if you do just a 45° rotation, only the shear component will be nonzero, a situation, which is clearly achieved by 90° rotation in Mohr's circle.

@Tomáš Létal Please check the edited question

I don't see a mistake, so maybe your notation is a bit different. If you switch $\sigma_x$ with $\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_x'$ and $\sigma_y'$ in your figure, it could flip the sign of $\frac{\sigma_x-\sigma_y}{2}$ in the end result of the derivation.

@Tomáš Létal Thanks a ton...I got the mistake....Since I have taken shear stress in positive direction along upward abscissa, the angle (2*theta) will be negative for CCW rotation
